# Hot water burn management

Tags: burns, antibiotic-cream, saline, second-degree-burn, buttocks

Background: In an attempt to relieve hemorroids I hurt myself with hot water on the buttocks near crack area, this started only two days ago. The burn area is not exceeding width of two fingers on each cheek, mostly inside the folded cheeks area and not on the exposed cheeks. Burn is red and painful but no blisters, with painful tingling, yet pain is relatively controlled with non-steroidal analgesics. When I clean the burn in the morning it sheds very little blood on the cleaning tissue but bloods stops after I gently swap the burn 2-3 times. I am avoiding sitting down or laying on my back as it worsen the pain. 
Question 1: is this a second degree burn? I clean with saline and apply antibiotic cream three times daily, is this enough? 
Should I also apply an antibiotic spray and or any steroidal cream?
Question 2: I can't cover the burn given difficulty of making the dressing stable with every movement, is this ok?